# Cassandra Django database backend support

Tags: python, django, cassandra, cql

Are there any drivers or libraries that support using cassandra as a database backend in django(clean integration in the settings.py)?  Ideally witch cql support as it seems other methods may become deprecated in the near future.

Without going into large amounts of details the goal is to have two databases.  1 postgresql the other cassandra.  Both with entirely different data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django but there is a [python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver).

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-cassandra-engine to interact with a cassandra cluster from a django website.
you can find the documentation [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cassandra-engine/)